# Canceling gym membership while in recovery

Tags: contract-law

I was trying to cancel my gym membership because I had a surprise surgery that put me out of physical activity for a few months, and I couldn't leave the house for one month, but they told me that no matter what I need to come in to cancel without exceptions.

Can they say this? Now they're trying to charge me for the months that I was unable to attend for but still "had a membership" because I "never canceled".

I regret not trying to email them after the phone call, I would have much preferred to have a record of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it illegal for a fitness center to deny my request for a copy of my contract? Also is it illegal to cancel a membership via phone in Tennessee?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30378/is-it-illegal-for-a-fitness-center-to-deny-my-request-for-a-copy-of-my-contract)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions pertaining to cancellation of a contract are contained in the contract, that is there is no general "right to cancel a contract", apart from certain 3-day window rights in some jurisdictions. For example, Washington state has some specific cancellation laws, summarized [here](https://www.atg.wa.gov/cancellation-rights#HowToCancel). If the contract does not allow for cancellation, then you can't cancel the contract. I assume that your contract does have a cancellation clause: then you could have to see what that clause actually states.

As it turns out, Florida has a law ([Fla Stat. 501.017](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0500-0599/0501/Sections/0501.017.html)) which regulates health studio (gym) contracts, requiring certain clauses above the signature box.  One required clause per (1)(b)2 is

> that notice of intent to cancel by the buyer shall be given in writing
>   to the health studio.

However,

> If the health studio wishes to enforce the contract after receipt of
>   the notice, it may request the department to determine the sufficiency
>   of the notice.

This means that if they want to enforce the contract after a cancellation, they *may* request "the department" (Department of Agriculture and Consumer Services) to rule whether the notice was according to the contract (as mandated by law).

It will also contain under (1)(d)

> A provision for the cancellation of the contract if the buyer dies or
>   becomes physically unable to avail himself or herself of a substantial
>   portion of those services which he or she used from the commencement
>   of the contract until the time of disability, with refund of funds
>   paid or accepted in payment of the contract in an amount computed by
>   dividing the contract price by the number of weeks in the contract
>   term and multiplying the result by the number of weeks remaining in
>   the contract term. The contract may require a buyer or the buyer’s
>   estate seeking relief under this paragraph to provide proof of
>   disability or death. A physical disability sufficient to warrant
>   cancellation of the contract by the buyer is established if the buyer
>   furnishes to the health studio a certification of such disability by a
>   physician licensed under chapter 458, chapter 459, chapter 460, or
>   chapter 461 to the extent the diagnosis or treatment of the disability
>   is within the physician’s scope of practice. A refund shall be issued
>   within 30 days after receipt of the notice of cancellation made
>   pursuant to this paragraph.

It appears, then, that you simply need to give notice in the correct form (written, with a doctor's notice). In case the club does not have the required provisions in the contract, the contract violates state law and is unenforceable.

Comment: Makes sense, I wasn't sure if it would jurisdiction based, or there were general laws about this, etc. but I'll have to see what it says. I should have added the Florida tag as well